# MSSQL Sort by 2 columns then update a sort column

Tags: sql-server, sorting

I've got a table of items, the items can either be associated with a date or a category or both.

I now need to update a sort column so I can order the items on screen, so something like this;

| Item | Category | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | Cat1 | 02/08/21 |
| Item2 | Cat2 | 03/08/21 |
| Item3 | Cat1 | 03/08/21 |
| Item4 | Cat1 | 03/08/21 |
| Item5 | Cat2 | 02/08/21 |
| Item6 | Cat2 | 03/08/21 |

but when I've added the sort column I need it to end up like this;

| Item | Category | Date | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | Cat1 | 02/08/21 | 1 |
| Item5 | Cat2 | 02/08/21 | 1 |
| Item3 | Cat1 | 03/08/21 | 1 |
| Item4 | Cat1 | 03/08/21 | 2 |
| Item6 | Cat2 | 03/08/21 | 1 |
| Item2 | Cat2 | 03/08/21 | 2 |

So it does something like "select * from items order by category asc, date asc then it gives each "grouping" a count starting from 1 and incrementing for each member of that group, then going back to 1 for the next group. so items with same category and date are given an order, then the next set of items with the same category but a different date are given an order starting at 1 again and so on.

Hope I've explained this correctly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category, Date ORDER BY Item) [Order]
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Date, Category;
```

Comment: That's brilliant, just what I needed. I did look into row_number but I must have missed something as it was ordering the table, showing the row numbers but it was starting at 1 and continuing incrementing until the end of the table